# Why would macro performance be fast in VBA designer but slow in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a modified (by me) VBA framework to produce a file in Excel 2017.  I didn't write the original framework, and it's quite extensive, so I won't share the code here.  I recognize that this makes it harder for others to assist.

If I run the macro from within the VBA design window, it completes reasonably quickly (several minutes, but I can live with that).  If I activate the macro from the Excel window, however -- via a button on a worksheet, for example -- it takes HOURS to complete.

I've got screen updating, display status bar, automatic calculations, display alerts, and display page breaks all turned off.  I'm also minimizing the Excel window.

My question is, what's different about the VBA design window compared to the Excel window when it comes to running macros?  Why would I get different performance between the two?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any event handlers which are firing? In any event, without a [mcve], it is hard to do any more than make random guesses.

Comment: My guess: unqualified ranges and extensive use of `.Select`!